# multiple record insert creating many duplicate records

Tags: plugin-development, database, wpdb

I want to loop over an array and store the records in the database. This is working but for some reason it is creating 30 odd records instead of just 4. I put this code into a very basic custom plugin and just loaded the home page to make it insert the data. I only loaded the page once yet as mentioned, it added 30 something records instead of just 4.

```
$data = [
    'A' => 1,
    'B' => 2,
    'C' => 3,
    'D' => 4
];

global $wpdb;
$tblname= $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
$charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
    $wpdb->insert( $tblname, array(
    'label' => $key,
    'value' => $value,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Make sure to hook that code to a specific action, otherwise it will run on every page load, including AJAX calls, cron tasks, and even 404s for missing images. These requests may run in the background without any visible indication.

Comment: Thank you. What action would you suggest?

Comment: Maybe [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) for the test, In actual use you would probably need something more specific, depending on what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Great, thanks. It should actually be in the end used with wp cron and run every x number of hours.

Comment: @fuxia your suggestion works great, thanks! I want to close this now but there is no answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running in WP cron, you'll define your function, and then hook the function to the cron's name.

Example:

```
function cron_function() {
    ...
}

add_action( 'cron_hook', 'cron_function' );

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'one_minute', 'cron_hook' );
}
```

See WordPress developer resource for more info:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/